# How do I chase down the cause of this TFS Automated Build Error?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, build-automation, tfsbuild

I have a solution that contains a website project and several projects that hold support classes. Each project serves a separate basic function: Configuration, Data, Identity, Business Objects, etc. When I open the solution in VS2008, it builds perfectly. It operates, runs, debugs, and experiences no compile or JIT exceptions.

After generated an automated build definition in TFS 2010, the build runs and compiles all of the sub-projects in order. They are all targeted to "Debug|Mixed Platforms" because the documentation I read trying to trace down my error indicates that this is necessary for website projects. I can see in the build log where all of the freshly compiled libraries and all of the third party libraries are copied both to the `\Binaries` directory and to the website's `\bin` directory. Then the very next lines in the log are:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /MySolution -p ..\MySolution\ -u -f -d -fixednames D:\TFS\b\308\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\MySolution\ 
D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\MySolution\SomeFolder\SomePage.aspx.vb(15): error BC30456: 'MyProperty' is not a member of 'Some_UserControl_ForPage'. [D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\Solution Files\MySolution.sln]
Done Building Project "D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\Solution Files\MySolution.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\Solution Files\MySolution.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(MySolution target) -> 
  D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\MySolution\SomeFolder\SomePage.aspx.vb(15): error BC30456: 'MyProperty' is not a member of 'Some_UserControl_ForPage'. [D:\TFS\b\308\Sources\Solution Files\MySolution.sln]
```

The property in question for the user control belongs to a "grandparent" inheritance. The control itself inherits a custom WebUserControl in the business objects library. That class in turn inherits from a less specific WebUserControl that has this basic property. When the line of code is commented out, the error changes, but it is just another "not possible" error that happens further on down the build chain.

We have other website projects successfully automatically building and deploying from this build agent in all frameworks 2.0+. When I change various properties of the build definition (workspace, et al) or adjust the configuration of the build within the solution itself it produces no change in behavior. When the build is complete, all successfully built projects end up in the build folder. Additionally, this solution has a second less complex website project within it that successfully builds and ends up in the _PublishedWebsites folder of the build folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first course was to uncheck the `Use fixed naming and single page assemblies` setting the website properties. This eliminated the physical error. This was a swag from a colleague rather than a calculated move, but my best guess is that for some reason TFS is unable to resolve the nested references. While this eliminated the reference error, it present with a new error indicating an ambiguous namespace on a user control. The assumption is that since the website project is no longer restricted to single page assemblies, there may be multiple copies generated (why is beyond me) and this results in the ambiguity.

I do not fully understand the ins and outs of this solution, but having read about the problem in [this blog article by Aaron Hallberg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaronhallberg/archive/2006/09/12/750590.aspx), I understand there are differences between the compiler as it is run in the IDE and the compiler as it is run on the automated build agent. To sum up his response, the IDE automatically does not inject a -u to the MSBuild for websites. However, since TFS looks at the solution only rather than considering the website project, it looks for the setting `Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable`. If this setting is turned, it may result in ambiguous namespaces on controls. I do not understand why and reading his blog post did not clear anything up for me.

Unchecking the `Allow this precompiled site to be updated` in the website's property pages allowed the site to build properly, and since it is not a precompiled site it did not have any adverse impact on the build.